# Google App Scripts OnEdit Trigger Help to avoid "too many simultaneous invocations"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google sheets to keep track of program details and send emails based on the information in the sheet. Each google sheet tab has 3-5 different emails that can be sent. The emails are controlled by a simple script and an "onEdit" trigger, which looks for "Send!" to be selected in a column, and then sends the appropriate email. The issue is when making lots of changes to the sheet rapidly, all the different triggers fire and the app script fails either with the error message "Service using too much computer time for one day" or "Too many simultaneous invocations". Once these google app script limits are reached they take 24 hours to reset.

In the past I'd added "Utilities.sleep(2000)" with different time intervals to avoid the "too many simultaneous..." but that only wastes more runtime and gets me to the "too much computer time..." error. So, how can I modify the script code or triggers to still operate when "Send!" is selected in the spreadsheet, but not experience these other google sheets timeouts?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here's a sample of one of the email scripts. The triggers are the "on edit" type.

```
function SendDD01Confirmation() {

  Utilities.sleep(1000)

  var sheetNameToWatch = "DD";
  var columnNumberToWatch = 24; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  var valueToWatch = "Send!";

  var emailAddressColumn = 5;
  var namecolumn = 3;
  var datecolumn = 1;
  var datewrittencolumn = 6;
  var schoolcolumn = 2;
  var timescolumn = 7;

  var statuscolumn = 25;  
  var statusValue = "✓";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), emailAddressColumn).getValue();
  var name = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), namecolumn).getValue();
  var date = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), datecolumn).getValue();
  var datewritten = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), datewrittencolumn).getValue();
  var school = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), schoolcolumn).getValue(); 
  var times = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), timescolumn).getValue();

  var status = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),statuscolumn)  

  var emailSubject = "Program has been scheduled for " +date+ "!";

  var body = "Program is coming to your class! You are scheduled to receive a one-hour presentation on " +datewritten+ " at " +school+ ", with the following time(s):\n \n" +times+ "\n (Rest of email removed for brevities sake)";

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
       GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, body)
       status.setValue(statusValue);

       }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

}
```

Comment: Do the emails *have* to be sent instantly or could you set this on a 5-minute trigger for batches of emails instead?

Comment: Hey Ross, it would be fine with a 5-minute time based trigger. When I setup a time based trigger it doesn't work with this code and I couldn't figure out how to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

Your doing a lot of stuff in your code that you don't need to do.  For one thing put the code that checks for the correct sheet right at the top so you don't have to do a bunch of useless declarations. Secondly, get all of the data at one time as I did with the getValues() and it would be preferable not to use intermediatevariables for the data values and instead just used the actual data elements like data[0][1] etc...

```
function SendDD01Confirmation(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var n=sh.getName();
  if(n!="DD")return;//This is preferable close to the beginning of the function
  var statusValue = "✓";
  var data=sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,25).getValues();
  var emailAddress = data[0][4];//it would be better to remove these intermediate variables as well but it's a bit more difficult to trouble shoot.
  var name = data[0][2];
  var date = data[0][0];
  var datewritten = data[0][5];
  var school = data[0][1];
  var times = data[0][6];
  var status = data[0][24];
  var emailSubject = "Program has been scheduled for " +date+ "!";
  var body = "Program is coming to your class! You are scheduled to receive a one-hour presentation on " +datewritten+ " at " +school+ ", with the following time(s):\n \n" +times+ "\n (Rest of email removed for brevities sake)";
  if (e.range.columnStart == 24 && e.value == "Send!") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, body);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,25).setValue(statusValue);
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

You could probably scrunch it down to this:

```
function SendDD01Confirmation(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var n=sh.getName();
  if(n!="DD")return;
  var statusValue = "✓";
  var data=sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,25).getValues();
  var emailAddress = data[0][4];//it would be better to remove these intermediate variables as well but it's a bit more difficult to trouble shoot.
  var emailSubject = "Program has been scheduled for " + data[0][0] + "!";
  var body = "Program is coming to your class! You are scheduled to receive a one-hour presentation on " + data[0][5] + " at " + data[0][1] + ", with the following time(s):\n \n" + data[0][6] + "\n (Rest of email removed for brevities sake)";
  if (e.range.columnStart==24 && e.value=="Send!") {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, body);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,25).setValue(statusValue);
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: Cooper, really appreciate your help in optimizing this code! I was playing with your version and it works. But would this solve my problems of "too many simultaneous invocations"? Even if I update all the emails to this better code, aren't all the triggers  together still going to be activating with every edit and thus leading to the same problems? thanks!

Comment: Never more than 3 simultaneous users. But most of the time just 1 user. And the OnEdit triggers are only setup for the manager of the sheet, so the emails come from them.

Comment: You use the term "triggers" plural.  Are there more than one onEdit() triggers?  If so, why not combine them.

Comment: Yes, multiple triggers. At this point, I'd broken each email send into its own script with its own trigger. I could probably combine them into a single function just using an 'if' function to determine which msg needs to be sent.

Comment: Are these triggers simple triggers or installable?

Comment: These are the simple triggers you can easily add to projects at script.google.com. And I tested combining all the emails for each sheet into one script using your shorter code and it works nicely. That reduces the number of triggers I'm using by 70%. I'm guessing that reduction in triggers combined with your cleaner code, might be enough to solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Please be sure to exclude pages that are not involved as soon as possible in the script.  Remember onEdit triggers fire on any user edit of any sheet (tab).